# About Spark UnsafeShuffleWriter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization

I have two questions about UnsafeShuffleWriter, `UnsafeShuffleWriter` would be used when all three of the following conditions hold:

1. The shuffle dependency specifies no aggregation or output ordering.
2. The shuffle serializer supports relocation of serialized values (this is currently supported by KryoSerializer and Spark SQL's custom serializers).
3. The shuffle produces fewer than 16777216 output partitions.

I am confused about the first two conditions.

1. Why should the shuffle dependency specify no aggregation or output ordering? I think it's quite good to use `UnsafeShuffleWriter` if mapSideCombine=false, no matter whether aggregation or ordering is specified.
2. Why the serializer must support relocation of serialized values, where relocation would be used?